# Is it possible to get a list of Cl/Cd values for various NACA Airfoils?

Tags: propeller, blade

There are a lot of links which give the shape of the airfoil for any given set of camber thickness, position and max. thickness values, but I would like to know if it is possible to get the Lift vs. Angle of attack graph, i.e., in turn lift curve slope, and also Cl/Cd values for every NACA airfoil specified.

Actually, I needed the values to begin the designing of a basic propeller blade for my project.

I have tried searching a lot. It would be really helpful if anyone could help me proceed.

Comment: I suggest you look into Xfoil: http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/, it's freely available software that is great for low speed modeling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the most important resource for airfoil data is the NACA (the predecessor of NASA) Report No.824 [*Summary of Airfoil Data*](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19930090976) by Abbott, Von Doenhoff and Stivers.

This report contains the description, generation and experimental data like variation of lift, drag and moment coefficients with angles of attack for a number of NACA airfoils.

You can also see NACA report No. 460 [*The Characteristics of 78 Related Airfoil Sections from the Tests in the Variable Density Wind Tunnel*](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19930091108&hterms=460&qs=Ntx%3Dmode%2520matchallpartial%26Ntk%3DAll%26N%3D4293947576%26Ntt%3D460) by Jacobs, Ward and Pinkerton.

Also, [*Aerodynamic characteristics of a large number of airfoils tested in the variable-density wind tunnel*](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19930090937&qs=Nm%3D4293947576|Author|Jacobs%2C%2520Eastman%2520N||4293947575|Author|Pinkerton%2C%2520Robert%2520M||4293947504|Author|Ward%2C%2520Kenneth%2520E||4294957998|Subject%2520Terms|AIRFOILS%26N%3D0) by     Pinkerton and Greenberg.

These are similar to the first report, but older.

Answer (score 0):

*Theory of Wing Sections* by Abbot and Doenhoff is a good one. I use that book to select my aerofoil and aerodynamic characteristics.

Comment: @J.Hougaard: Which link? there is no link... (I known this comes from your choice in the review queue)